# Is there an R function for extracting a number from a path name?

Tags: r, file

I have a list of files to read in from a folder. Some of them are in the csv format and some of them are in the pp format. I have two separate functions to read the files in based on which format it is.

Currently I have list of the files using the `list.files` command. I'd like to make a dictionary mapping an ID to its corresponding file name, for example `100` maps to /Users/Bob/Box/here/is/some/data/100.csv while `50` maps to /Users/Bob/Box/here/is/some/data/50.pp.

I'm looping through another set of ID's so the purpose of the dictionary is supposed to make it easier to extract the pathname corresponding to an ID. Is there a way to construct this dictionary? I was thinking maybe if there was a way to automatically extract the ID from the pathname while processing the folder?

Comment: Get the file paths and extract the number with regex?

Comment: `tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(pth))` .In fact you may be able to use the `patttern` argument in `list.files` seeing as you using that already.

Comment: ... to be clear, instead of trying to parse the numbers use two list.files calls: `list.files(dir, pattern=".pp$", full.names=TRUE)` and similarly for the csvs.

Comment: Regular expressions to extract things like integers and floats are well-tested here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html and https://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here: https://stla.github.io/stlapblog/posts/Numextract.html

To extract number from a character vector, you can use the library `stringr` and create a function to extract number:

```
> library(stringr)
> numextract <- function(string){str_extract(string, "[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+")
}  
> numextract("30.5ml")
[1] "30.5"

# With your example:
> numextract("/Users/Bob/Box/here/is/some/data/++---100.csv")
[1] "-100."

# you can add 'as.numeric' to extract only numerical value
> as.numeric(numextract("/Users/Bob/Box/here/is/some/data/++---100.csv"))
[1] -100
```

Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: While this regex works, they can be rather circuitous at times. For instance, with `-*` (no need to backslash-escape it, btw), it will match more than one negative sign, which will cause `as.numeric` to fail (try `as.numeric(numextract("--23"))`). A better regex might be `"[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+"` (from https://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html).

Comment: @r2evans, you're right, I just tested it, your regex formula is better and take in consideration for several signs before the number, I edited the code to reflect that. Thanks for the improvement.